# Is it possible to fill all free space in jquery fullcalendar with default event?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

For example, i have one event for current month, that starts 22.11.2013 21:00 and ends 22.11.2013 22:00. For all other hours/days i have blank space. I would like to fill in all this space with default event, so for current month result would be:

- 01.11.2013 00:00 - 22.11.2013 21:00 default event
- 22.11.2013 21:00 - 22.11.2013 22:00 user defined event
- 22.11.2013 22.00 - 01.12.2013 00:00 default event

currently i am adding events dynamically using addEventSource function (i have not only simple events, but recurrent too), is it possible to fill blank space without custom implementation?

Jquery fullcalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

P.S. Or perhaps it is possible to somehow retrieve blank spaces to render events?

Comment: Dont think thats possible with the API, but it can be acomplished with custom implementation.

Comment: Yeah, finally i made such support on server-side, and then just was transferring generated events for specified period of time to calendar.